# Unity Same Material but individual Draw Calls?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a scene in which I generate a grid using a Prefab with LineRenderer component by making clones of the prefab and setting their points.

```
    Instantiate(prefab);
```

[image]

But the problem is I get 27 Draw Calls even though all of the lines have same material, what can be the reason for this and how do I fix it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem only MeshRenderers and Particle Systems allow batching, take a look at
[this](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DrawCallBatching.html)

Comment: there is also non uniform scaling that will break the batching

Answer (score 0):

you should use static batching , check your game objects as static